# app closing while back button is pressed

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I am developing a mobile app using angular js, cordova , ionic and using intel xdk to build. Here my problem is whenever i click the back button in mobile device, app get closed itself instead of redirecting to previous page.Is that ionic problem? 
  Also tried **addEventListener**

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

 function onBackKeyDown() {
   alert();
    $location.path('/sandhyavMor');
}
```

Here, still the app getting closed after firing the alert. Also i am using intel xdk **media plugin**.

so what may be the problem.

Comment: Your problem could be with routing of AngularJS. Can you provide the code for the routing?

Comment: I hardly believe that has anything to do with routing tbh.

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.Use it in app.js

```
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform,$state,$log, $rootScope,$ionicHistory) {

 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
   if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {
        $ionicHistory.goBack();
    } else {
        $state.go($rootScope.previousState);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}, 101);
});
```

Comment: Is 'starter' is my ng-app name? or predefined one?

Comment: ya.starter is ur ng-app name

Comment: Hi, here is the plunker link [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/FRIOBy5BiGVtdD7BDU0d?p=catalogue) . This will not work just wanna show how i wrote code for routing

Comment: But no improvement bro @ mahesh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111132/discussion-between-sibi-and-mahesh-bhusanoor).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a previous view to go back to?  Are there tabs in your app?